# Pass on a client/game-session verification from one server to another? (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, server, connection

I am pretty new to programming and I am trying to create a simple Login-Server for a simple online game.
So basically the client connects to the Login-Server which is checking the password and accountname with a mysql-query. Thats how far I have got right now.

Now I want to create some kind of THING, that links the clients connection (adress?) to his game account. So whenever the client sends something i can make sure it was sent to the corresponding game account.
I want to be able to pass that THING (how ever it may look like) on to ANOTHER SERVER(!), that handles game logics, chat, etc.

So what kind of "thing" would that be I am looking for? Whats the most easy method, to store the connection of a client to his game account on the server side?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question is way to broad and unspecific for someone to really step in an help you. You should show relevant code samples and be clear on what circumstances and environment you are working in. Also, it is not really clear what you mean by _server_, _another server_, _address_ etc.

Comment: since i havent got my login-server running right now (still fixing some error with mysql resultset.getstring() ) its basically a question about architecture and not about actual code. I dont see that much a need of code samples, why would you need them? Regarding server: by server i mean an application that can be connected to by some clients. Regarding address: as i told, i dont have a clue how network works, so dont expect me to know all the vocabulary.

Comment: @PatSch SO's scope is quite focused and is geared towards questions that involve specific code problems. See [what topics can be asked about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might be on-topic at [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). They seem to welcome more conceptual questions. Check out their help page before asking. You may also be interested in [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).

Comment: @FrankTan when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at [Sockets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm). The THING you describe is a new socket for every client that handles all the network traffic. Sockets are secure enough for your program and on internet you can find a great deal about them.

You cannot simply pass a socket to another server in Java. The client will have to make a new connection to the other server it must connect to. However, it's very unusual to split up the network traffic between different servers because it's much easier and more efficient (for the client) to send everything to the same server. Try to stick with one server for the program and one socket per user.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I will for sure look at those sockets. But regarding the splitting of the connection: Since i will need different servers for instancing, should i have one server handling all the user input and giving it to the other servers? Wouldnt that cause severe problems, if any of the servers are not responding?

Comment: @PatSch That's right. If any of the other servers are not responding and the server must have the response to be able to continue, it would cause severe lag. It's very, very convenient to process everything on the same server, but if you really must have multiple servers for some reason, then you'll have to make one socket for the client to the server, one socket from that server to another server it wants to communicate with, maybe yet another socket from that server to yet another server, etc.

Comment: fine, i guess i got it. Thanks for your help, i think i should start reading on sockets now :)